# Unique combinations inside a models.py-class?

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique

Is there a way to define a unique combination inside my django-model?

For example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    value_01 = models.Foreignkey(xyz, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value_02 = models.Charfield(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
```

Instead of making these two values unique on their own, is it possible to define a unique combination of these two values?

Comment: Previously you'd want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together, but now it's recommended to make a https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint under https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints

Comment: Thank you for this quick answering!